# How can I fix the "invalid input" error in my command line style Wordle clone Telegram bot?

Tags: kotlin, telegram, telegram-bot

I am trying to write a Telegram bot that simulates the Wordle game. The bot prompts the user to enter a 5-letter word and provides feedback on whether the guess is correct or not. However, the bot repeatedly sends an "invalid input" error message even when valid input is entered.

Here is the relevant code snippet:

```
class MyAmazingBot : TelegramLongPollingBot() {

    override fun onUpdateReceived(update: Update) {
        var turns = 0
        var last = ""

        if (update.hasMessage() && update.message.hasText()) {
            val message = SendMessage()
            message.chatId = update.message.chatId.toString()
            val input = update.message.text

            if (input == "Wordle") {
                val strings = arrayListOf(
                    "dictionary file",
                    "candidate words file"
                )
                val listOfWords = strings[0]
                val candidate = strings[1]
                val randomWord = getRandomWord(candidate)
                message.text = "Please enter a 5-letter word: "
                execute(message)
                while (true) {
                    var playerWord: String = ""
                    if (update.hasMessage() && update.message.hasText()) {
                        playerWord = update.message.text
                        if (playerWord == "/exit") {
                            message.text = "The game is over."
                            execute(message)
                            exitProcess(0)
                        }

                        turns++
                        if (!checkString(playerWord)) {
                            message.text = "Invalid input. Please enter a valid 5-letter word."
                            execute(message)
                            continue
                        }

                        if (!File(listOfWords).readLines().contains(playerWord)) {
                            message.text = "The input word isn't included in my words list."
                            execute(message)
                            continue
                        } else if (playerWord == randomWord) {
                            message.text = "Correct! The solution was found after $turns tries."
                            execute(message)
                            break
                        } else {
                            val match = findMatches(playerWord, randomWord)
                            val first: String = match.substring(0, 5)
                            last += match.substring(5, match.length)
                            message.text =
                                "Matching letters: ${
                                    last.toSet().sorted().joinToString("")
                                }\nIncorrect positions: $first"
                            execute(message)
                        }
                    } else {
                        message.text = "Please enter a 5-letter word: "
                        execute(message)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

How can I modify the loop or update request to fix this issue?

Comment: What the checkString function do?

Comment: viacheslav-smityukh It checks to see if the input string matches the 5 letters alphabetical characters only format, I can provide it if you want.

Comment: I'm not familiar with `Kotlin` and Telegram bot, but you are checking if `update.message.text == "Wordle"` because `input = update.message.text`. And ater that you are checking `playerWord` which is the same as `update.message.text`. So `playerWord == input == "Wordle"` everytime. If `Kotlin` doesn't doing some magic that I don't understand this logic is not correct. Does `execute(message)` update `update` under the hood?